# Change String color depending on value in Java

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java programming and trying to create an app in Android where the value changes color depending on the calculations.

```
public void calculate(View view) {
    EditText spindleSpeed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.spindle_speed);
    String speedString=spindleSpeed.getText().toString();
    int speed=Integer.parseInt(speedString);                 
    EditText diameter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tool_diameter);
    String diaString=diameter.getText().toString();   
    int dia=Integer.parseInt(diaString);            
    EditText feedRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.feed_rate);
    String feedString=feedRate.getText().toString();   
    int feed=Integer.parseInt(feedString);             
    EditText numberOfTeeth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_of_teeth);
    String teethString=numberOfTeeth.getText().toString();   
    int teeth=Integer.parseInt(teethString);                
    double feedPerTooth = ((feed*1.0)/(speed*teeth));
    double cuttingSpeed = (dia*3.14*speed)/(1000);
    String   FPT = new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(feedPerTooth);
    String surfaceSpeed = new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(cuttingSpeed);
```

Its this section below which i am having trouble with, how do get my text to change color depending on value?

```
    if (feedPerTooth >0.35){
        String attrs = new TextAttributes(Color.BLUE).format(feedPerTooth;
       FPT.getColor("#FF0000").format(feedPerTooth);
    } else if (feedPerTooth<0.07){
        FPT = "<font color=#FF0000>";
    } else ;
```

Any help or guidance will be appreciated :)

Comment: why is this question tagged as js??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to set color of a `TextView` use this : `textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F5DC49"));`

Comment: @AwaisMunawar nice to hear that, could you set my answer as accepted then :)

Answer (score 0):

String objects have no color attibute so this is not the best way

```
 if (feedPerTooth >0.35){
        String attrs = new TextAttributes(Color.BLUE).format(feedPerTooth);
```

you should instead use the method `#setError`

```
 diameter.setError( "feedPerTooth is to high!" )
```

Comment: thanks but I cant seem to get it to work. I just used Entea's method below :)